# Как список перевести в набор цифр?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, int

Есть такой список:

```
one = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

С помощью чего привести в нем элементы к типу int?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот так: `int("1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наиболее питоново, коротко и красиво будет применить к каждому элементу списка функцию `int` с помощью функции `map`:

```
map(int, one)
```

Но если будете использовать результат не как перечисление (например, в foreach), а с произвольным доступом, то придётся ещё потом преобразовать получившийся итератор в список:

```
list(map(int, one))
```

Comment: Я использовал второй способ но выдает ошибку :      small_3=list(map(int,small_2))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['                                Что это ?

Comment: @Tryr покажите что у вас точно лежит в small_2, подозреваю, что у вас кавычки где-то не там стоят и квадратная скобка попала внутрь строки каким-то образом

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, первая строчка выполнение команды print(small_2), если важно, то у меня была задача убрать "\n"," ' " может где то напутал, если стоит могу кинуть код?

Comment: Я тут поигрался проблема не в "\n", " ' ".

Comment: @Tryr Что-то тут не так. Попробуйте напечатать такие штуки: print(len(small_2)) и print(list(map(len,small_2)))

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, вторая строка print(len(small_2)) , третья и т.д print(list(map(len,small_2)))

Comment: @Tryr Похоже, у вас этот small_2 вовсе не список, а одна большая строка и итерируется она как одиночные символы поэтому, а не как список

Comment: Контрольная проверка: print(type(small_2))

Comment: У вас по факту что-то типа small_2 = '["350000", "350000", "350000"]' при печати на экран это неотличимо от списка, а по сути это просто строка

Comment: Я использовал .splitlines(), и все заработало, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @CrazyElf А что за `foreach`?

Comment: @SourSourse Блин, я опять C# и Python между собой путаю ))  В Python, конечно, есть только for, который по сути foreach ))

Comment: @CrazyElf :) А я подумал еще цикл ввели.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
one = [int(i) for i in one]
```

Comment: А можно через map()

Comment: @Nobody безусловно, но этот по-моему более читабельный

Comment: foreach если написать будет ещё более читабельно, но это не повод )  map красиво и коротко